# React/NextJS - Why am i not getting an error when value is null

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, next.js

I am trying to prevent anybody from adding a comment unless they have an avatar (or are not logged in for that matter). At the moment though, it doesnt prevent, it successfully adds to firestore back end and state gets updated with the new comment. I have a console log that is showing that the ava value is indeed null, so cant understand why it doesnt work?

```
  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        console.log(ava)
        e.preventDefault();
        if (ava === null) {
            setError("You must have an avatar to add a comment, please update your profile in the top right corner.");
            console.error("Avatar not set");
            console.log(ava)
            setTimeout(() => {
                router.push('/profile');
            }, 3000);
            return
        } else {
            try {
                await addDoc(collection(db, "comments"), {
                    postedBy: displayName ? displayName : 'Anonymous',
                    avatar: ava ? ava : 'Anonymous',
                    text: writeComment,
                    recipeId: recipeId,
                    createdAt: serverTimestamp()
                });
                setWriteComment("");
                setSuccessMessage("Comment added successfully");
                setOpenSnackbar(true);
            } catch (err) {
                setError("Error occurred while adding the comment.");
                console.error("Error:", err);
            }
        }
    };
```

[image: Console log]

```
import {
    addDoc, getFirestore, collection, serverTimestamp
} from 'firebase/firestore';
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
const db = getFirestore()
const auth = getAuth();

const Addcomment = ({ recipeId }) => {
    const router = useRouter()

    const [user, setUser] = useState(auth.currentUser);
    const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState(user?.displayName);
    const [ava, setAva] = useState("");
    const [writeComment, setWriteComment] = useState("")
    const [successMessage, setSuccessMessage] = useState("");
    const [error, setError] = useState("");
    const [openSnackbar, setOpenSnackbar] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const unsubscribe = auth.onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
            setUser(user);
            setDisplayName(user?.displayName);
            setAva(user?.photoURL);
        });
        return () => unsubscribe();
    }, []);
```

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of your console?

Comment: Also, a question, from where this ava variable assignment is coming from?

Comment: Sure, i have edited the original post now with a screenshot of the null i get, the error above it is relation to a different component for rendering the recipe, not the comments error, that i know about (unique key value). In terms of how ava is defined, it is pulled into state using a firebase get auth function, which works fine in other components and if the value is not null i do successfully get my avatar as expected etc